# AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'selection_point'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to make a drop down menu and I am getting this error below. I'm not really understanding why since I've used alt.Chart and alt.binding_select before and it didn't get any problems. I'm a little familiar with vegalite, and I'm trying out vega altair in colab.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f38e2e2742ea> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 source1_select = alt.selection_point(fields=data.experience_level, bind=source1_drop)

AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'selection_point'
```

My code so far:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("ds_salaries.csv")

# wanted to add drop down menu to this 
graph1 = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode( 
    x='count(job_title)',
    y='job_title'
)

source1_drop = alt.binding_select(options=['EN', 'SE'], name="Experience Level (Source 1)")
source2_drop = alt.binding_select(options=['EN', 'SE'], name="Experience Level (Source 2)")

# Error here
source1_select = alt.selection_point(fields=data.experience_level, bind=source1_drop)

alt.__file__
# '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/altair/__init__.py'
alt.__path__
# ['/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/altair']
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, since I followed the documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Turns out I was looking at v5 documentation whilst colab was running v4